# Не могу скомпилировать код, нид хелп

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char    *ft_strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
int i;
int o;

i = 0;
o = 0;
while (dest[i] != '\0')
    i++;
while (src[o] != '\0')
{
    dest[i] = src[o];
    i++;
    o++;
}
dest[i] = '\0';
return (dest);
}

int main()
{
printf("%s", ft_strcat("hello", "world"));
return 0;
}
```

подскажите что я сделал не так ?))

Comment: приложите код в тело вопроса в виде текста, а не в виде скриншота. Приведите код и сообщение об ошибке, если таковые имеются.

Comment: Константные строки нельзя модифицировать + вам нужно увеличить размер `dest` чтобы вы могли дописать туда что-то. Используйте `malloc` и `realloc`.

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. Этот код прекрасно компилируется. Работать правильно он не будет, но с компиляцией проблем нет.

Comment: segmentation fault ошибка и он не компилируется

Comment: @Андрей Код компилируется, затем запускается на выполнение, выполняется до строки, в которой вы пытаетесь записывать в `dest` и вот тут программа падает с ошибкой. Не пользуйтесь online IDE, которая всё делает за вас, за сценой, а то так и не поймёте, когда происходит ошибка.

Comment: @AnT Этот код компилируется, если забыть "-Wall -Werror".  Но кто с экспертов смотрит в предупреждения... (pedantic / Wextra также желательны)

Comment: @Андрей: Если у вас "segmentation fault ошибка", значит ваш код успешно скомпилировался. В коде, который "не компилируется" в принципе не может быть никакой "segmentation fault ошибки".

Comment: @KoVadim: А что вы увидели на `-Wall`? Вот вам запуск с `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/625a741c10c013c4. Полная тишина от компилятора.

Comment: в Вашем выводе действительно ничего нет. Но скопировав и перезапустив пример, получил это `main.cpp:25:40: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]
 printf("%s", ft_strcat("hello", "world"));`

Comment: @KoVadim А при чём тут С++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Давайте пофиским код минимальными изменениями. И что бы ещё и утечек не было

Предлагаю вот такой main

```
int main()
{
    char f1[256] = "hello";
    char f2[256] = "world";
    printf("%s", ft_strcat(f1, f2));
    return 0;
}
```

256 байт хватит всем (Билл (c)).

Почему происходит проблема? "hello" - это константный массив. Его как  бы изменять нельзя - компилятор имеет право (и даже так делает) разместить его в памяти, которую нельзя изменять. Это как в Поле Чудес пойти и поменять самому буквы - в лучше случае зал просто посмеется. Но изменять ещё пол беды. Вы пытаетесь писать за пределы этого константного массива. Это как в пытаться открыть буквы там, где их нет... Тут уже могут и охрану вызвать.